# Build error: Could not find SDK "Microsoft.WinJS.Version=0.6"

Tags: windows-8, build

I am trying to build a sample Win8 app with Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8. This sample was posted before the final release of Win8 and VS2012. I have changed all the callouts for "//Microsoft.WinJS.0.6/..." to be "//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/..." yet I still get this build error: Could not find SDK "Microsoft.WinJS.Version=0.6", in file Microsoft.Common.Targets. The Error List says this file is at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\, but there is no such file there.

My other builds of JS apps I code from scratch work without a problem. How can I fix this old sample app?

Comment: Which example are you building? You may be lacking references, if this is a C# app, I have never experienced this issue when building using JS

Comment: Have you checked for references to 0.6 in the project file? Code files only won't be sufficient.

Comment: Under your project in VS's solution explorer, expand References, right click WinJS 0.6, and select Remove. Then right click Reference, choose Add Reference, then select WinJS 1.0. This is always necessary in addition to changing the code references.